# Minimal installation requirements for compiling WP7 projects on a build server

Tags: windows-phone-7, continuous-integration

I'm attempting to find the minimum installation requirements for getting WP7 projects compiling on a Windows 2008 R2 build server. I'll be looking into automated testing using the emulator at a later point, but right now I'm stuck on the build side.

I realise this approach won't be supported and I'm willing to trash the VM at a later date if an update proves to be incompatible (assuming I get it to work at all)

I'm also aware of the [workaround for installing the entire SDK on Windows 2008 R2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/02/10005980.aspx), but I'm trying to avoid installation of Visual Studio (it's now become a curiosity more than anything else)

As it stands, I've installed the following from the SDK ISO:

- WCU\Silverlight4\silverlight_sdk.msi
- WCU\WindowsPhone\WindowsPhoneExtensions.msi
- WCU\WindowsPhone\VS_SDEProLightup-enu.msi

At this point, it is able to locate all the required MSBuild target files and even compiles the project. The problem appears at the end of the process during the `XapPackager` target, when it errors with:

> Xap packaging failed. Unable to load DLL 'zlib114.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Using Process Monitor, I can see that MSBuild finds the dll in the WP7 MSBuild targets directory that installs with the SDK with the only error being "FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS" error to a CreateFileMapping+SyncTypeCreateSection, which it then falls back to a SyncTypeOther, which succeeds. Despite this, MSBuild still continue to look for the dll is all the other standard locations (Framework directory, SysWOW64, etc).

Any thoughts to why it might be failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using TFS, Justin Angel has a great post on [TFS2010 WP7 Continuous Integration](http://justinangel.net/TFS2010WP7ContinuousIntegration). Given that TFS is just wrapping around MSBuild, you may find this a particularly useful resource. When it comes to doing the unit test integration, Deyan Ginev from Telerik has a [series of posts](http://blogs.telerik.com/DeyanGinev/Posts.aspx) that covers this.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I ended up fixing the zlib problem by using the dll from the Silverlight SDK, rather than the WP SDK.